# LC Power filter not achieving modelled attenuation

Tags: power-supply, filter, passive-networks

I am testing an LC power filter and my real world measurements of high frequency (~1.5Mhz) switching spikes show that the attenuation is not remotely close to what my design model suggested.

### Situation / Requirements

I have a 6A 7.5V Mean Well SMPS. [GST60A07-P1J](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/GST60A/GST60A-SPEC.PDF)

It powers ~250 [WS2812 addressable RGB LEDs](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf)

It's noisy, but an otherwise excellent supply. Even with only a small resistive load of 22 Ohm at ~300mA, (without the WS2812 attached, which run PWM internally so that would be worse) the output looks like this - AC coupled, so zero centered:

[image: SMPS output]

The main control loop of the SMPS is rippling at ~ 1Khz. This part is fine because we can clean that up with an LDO. What is not fine, is those switching spikes. They are about 400mV+ peak-to-peak and have very high frequency content which an LDO will not filter. Here is one of those spikes:

[image: Spike zoomed in]

Just a visual estimate says that fundamental oscillation of that spike is about 1-2Mhz. My rudimentary FFT capability says there is content above the noise floor up to 5Mhz, which seems about right.

The challenge is that this same power supply needs to also supply the micro controller which runs the WS2812s and also includes some relatively simple analogue circuits and some rudimentary single channel audio. So I am trying to clean this mess up before feeding it to the uC and the analogues. I only need about 200mA of clean supply for the "brains". During testing I am using a 5V LDO, but the final design will be 3.3V.

### Attempted solution

The only solution I know how to filter such high frequency content in a power line is a passive LC filter. Semiconductors can't keep up. LDOs PSRR drops quickly. "Capacitor multiplier" type circuits suffer from the same issue - the BJT can't keep up.

I am using the highest HF PSRR LDO I know of downstream of my LC filter: The slightly dated [LM2931](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/ONSM/ONSMS34347/ONSMS26170-1.pdf). This deals with the 1Khz SMPS loop ripple just fine, but it barely touches those spikes.

So I attempted to design and test such an LC filter. I loosely followed [this process](https://www.tempoautomation.com/toms-circuits/power-supply-filter-design-for-pcb/).

I selected a corner frequency (fc = 1/(sqrt(L*C) * 2pi) of ~1kHz by chosing [this RLB0712-101KL 100uH inductor](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2360349.pdf) this [100uF Tantalum Capacitor](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1829545.pdf). Note these are through hole components, the final design will be SMC.

I modelled the filter in ngspice with this model circuit (parasitic model components calculated from datasheets, according to that article):

[image: Spice model]

The AC sweep simulation shows this:

[image: Simulation results]

Which is as expected from design and shows Vload / Vinput = -52db down (~ 66 - 14) @ 1Mhz and better up to 5Mhz. That would be a great result indeed, as the 400mV spikes would be squashed by factor 400x ( 10^(52/20) ) to ~ 1mV.

### Reality

I built a simple test rig on vero board. I kept all leads super short and the whole circuit is just 15x15mm including LC filter and LDO stage with 2 more caps:

[image]

So what's the result? Quite disappointing really. I get this:

[image]

The yellow channel is the input from the SMPS, and the blue channel (note the scale is 10x less) is the "FilterOutput" node on above schematic - equivalent to Vload in simulation. The peak-to-peak averages in that screenshot show at best a 10:1 attenuation. Not 400:1.   (The LDO does fine in getting rid of the 1Khz ripple, that's not the focus here, but it barely further improves the spikes).

### Questions

- Is my approach "sane"? Did I miss a trick?
- Why am I getting 40x less attenuation than the design simulation suggests? Component model? Through hole? Vero board construction ? 1-5Mhz is not very HF, really?
- What can I do to squash the spikes? Use a second stage LC filter? Recommended approach to design equations? 4th order Butterworth? Link to article?

Many thanks

Comment: For one thing, your parasitic model is off. The SRF of your inductor is given as 4.0 MHz, which would imply that the equivalent shunt capacitance is more like 16 pF, not the 0.4 pF that you show. Also, the link for the capacitor doesn't work for me, but I'm wondering why you would choose tantalum over ceramic in an application like this.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yup, thanks, that's a good spot. The 0.4pF is a mistake. I had 16pF in my calcs, but failed to transfer to the model correctly. That changes the HF knee in the Xfer function to 4Mhz. Still down a huge amount compared to real world measurement (although see doubt about that belowr). I am not experienced in picking caps for this kind of application. I appreciate that ceramics have lower ESR, but I only had 1uF in ceramic, and wanted a lower fc. Is that thinking wrong? In fact the datasheet of the LDO calls for a suggested 0.1uF ceramic on the input. that's in the test circuit.

Comment: Start by putting one of your 1 uF ceramics directly across the output of the Meanwell. Try putting a second one in parallel with your tantalum. Consider putting ferrite beads (or a common-mode choke) in series with both leads coming from the Meanwell.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks. So you are suggesting (once I get my measurement reality sorted - below), perhaps I don't even need an inductor? The meanwell already has one of those EMC ferrite bead lumps on the low voltage lead about 10in from my test circuit. Is that the same thing?

Comment: No, you can keep the inductor -- but you might try a smaller value with a higher SRF. As you are discovering, choosing a low cutoff frequency looks good on paper, but real components perform far from ideally, especially over many orders of magnitude in frequency.

Comment: @DaveTweed I have now solved my crazy grounding/probing issues (see below). So I may try to make a version with a 10uH inductor or 1uF ceramic cap as you suggested. Probably not both unless its a 2nd stage (overkill?), as modelling suggests attenuation won't be enough. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your scope probing is not ideal. Did you use this type of probing measurement to reduce to "loop" pick-up formed by a conventional scope's probe: -

[image]

[image]

You can do a simple test to prove it is your probe technique - connect probe top to where the earth clip connects and see what is picked-up - ideally there should be no signal picked up because probe tip = grounding point. I'll guess that you pick-up quite a bit of noise and spikes if you try this.

SMPS's are notorious for screwing with a badly connected probe and you probably need to use a ground spring: -

[image]

See also [this article](https://www.eetimes.com/power-tip-6-accurately-measuring-power-supply-ripple/#) on the same subject entitled Power Tip #6: Accurately Measuring Power Supply Ripple.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That did occur to me, and no I can't rule it out yet. I fiddled around with a less than ideal spring ground clip and got the same result. But I am not convinced I have 100% percent eliminated this possibility. 

Is my approach/design otherwise sane?

Comment: I would't use the inductor you chose or I might put one extra inductor in series that deals with stuff greater that the 4 MHz SRF of the one you chose. There is a possibility that the core is saturating - I didn't really see what DC current it was taking during the test but, do the simple measurement I mentioned of putting the probe tip to the grounding point and seeing how much noise you pick up.

Comment: After some more fiddling around, I would say scope probing is probably part of the issue. I get a similar size spike on the ground pin when probing with croc ground lead/antenna, so that's bad. BUT I still the same size spike on the ground pin when probing with a spring clip - one ground pin to another ground pin. Earth difference/loop between the SMPS and the scope? I have a new scope arriving in an hour, so that should provide a "second opinion".

Comment: Sounds like common mode spike voltage on both DC outputs now. Presumably one DC output is meant to be grounded at some point and the other is your DC voltage. If both together are jumping around then that could cause current pulses into your scope ground and this could manifest itself as false noise. Try measuring the DC negative line with respect to the power supply chassis and see what you get. Also try solidly grounding the negative DC output lead. Check also your earth on the power supply - maybe it has failed in some way?

Comment: Hmm. New scope. Same reality. Measuring the same 50mV p-p spikes on the ground pin, even if I deliberately and separately ground that pin, with croc clip or with a new and better ground spring. Nightmare. Grrr.

Comment: Yes, SMPSs can be a problem. Just keep at it and try and rule as many things out as possible. Where are you at in terms of spike measurement now?

Comment: Well, I have given up on the filter for now. I can't be trying to evaluate the attenuation of a filter when this is going on. So What I have is the MeanWell SMPS plugged into a power socket, the new DSO plugged into same outlet (have also tried different room). My circuit has been taken out altogether and I am just powering that 22Ohm resistor with the 7.5V Meanwell to apply a tiny load. I measure across the output. 500mV spikes. Same ones. But this is what gets me: I measure FROM the negative terminal of the MeanWell TO the negative terminal. Same 50mV spikes. Croc clip or spring.

Comment: Done some buzzing with multimeter. All seems fine. The scope is earthed correctly. The GND of the BNC jacks and the earth terminal on the front are near zero Ohms to the 240VAC Plus Earth terminal. 

The MeanWell is isolated, as you would expect. But I am using a separate wire from the front terminal of scope to the negative terminal of the MeanWell negative output terminal to ensure the point I am measuring is at the same earth potential. 

Same spikes. Other ideas? Do I need some kind of "super earth" conductor from front of scope. It's only a croc clip right now.

Comment: I think you are the point where external remote help is going to struggle.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Many thanks. I think I am making progress by progressively removing more wires. ;-) Will report back when (!!) I solve it.

Comment: Yeah, it's just grounding. That's the first time I have been forced to really dig into that . But if I ground my circuit by pressing one of the ground pin headers up against the scope's front ground terminal (!!), then the spikes all but disappear into the noise floor. 5mV p-p which is 10x better. And that's without using the ground spring on the probe, because I ran out of hands! Any length of wire for the grounding of my circuit and I have 50mV spikes. So does that mean my circuit works?? Guess so. Anyway thanks. I am going to accept your answer, it was close and got me in right direction.

Comment: Great, a bit of digging and you got there. It's a little risky but sometimes EEs remove the ground pin from the plug of their o-scope to prove the same thing. I didn't want to mention that because it's a little dodgy to do and it's easy to forget that you've done it.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard about that trick. Never had to try to do it. Best to avoid...